# All unique combinations of a set of sets of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have an arbitrary amount of elements, each with a specified set of values, what can I do to get all possible combinations with a value from each element's set?

For example, let's say I have:

```
elems = {"A": (0, 1), "B": (-1, -5)}
```

What can I do to get the following?

```
({"A": 0, "B": -1}, {"A": 0, "B": -5}, {"A": 1, "B": -1}, {"A": 1, "B": -5})
```

Input/output don't need to use dicts, but I figured that's the easiest way to represent it.
Assume dict order matters.

I would like to know a way that:

1. Does not assume there are just 2 elements like in the example.
2. Does not assume the sets for all elements have an equal length.

It is somewhat like listing all inputs for a truth table.

Comment: would `itertools.product()` work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a nested list/dictionary comprehension, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) to generate all combinations of the values, and then `zip`ing each result tuple from that to the keys to generate the key/value pairs to make up each dictionary result. Here's an example using a slightly more complicated version of your data:

```py
import itertools

elems = {"A": (0, 1), "B": (-1, -5), "C": (1, 2, 3) }

keys = elems.keys()
res = [dict(zip(keys, p)) for p in itertools.product(*elems.values())]
```

Output:

```
[
 {'A': 0, 'B': -1, 'C': 1},
 {'A': 0, 'B': -1, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 0, 'B': -1, 'C': 3},
 {'A': 0, 'B': -5, 'C': 1},
 {'A': 0, 'B': -5, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 0, 'B': -5, 'C': 3},
 {'A': 1, 'B': -1, 'C': 1},
 {'A': 1, 'B': -1, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 1, 'B': -1, 'C': 3},
 {'A': 1, 'B': -5, 'C': 1},
 {'A': 1, 'B': -5, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 1, 'B': -5, 'C': 3}
]
```

Comment: You can just do: `dict(zip(keys, p))`

Comment: @flakes good point, wasn't thinking. I've updated the answer.

Comment: What is the solution if one of the values in the dictionary is boolean? I tried this method and it didn't work.

Comment: @user1751189 Without seeing your data I'm not sure why that would be. I'm currently on holiday though so I suggest asking a new question, referring back to this one if you need to.